# Javascript inside controller array not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to make switch button with action form on change inside a controller, javascript can't work, no request...

this my controller include jquery in controller ajax server side datatables...

## ajax_list.php

```
public function ajax_list()
    {
        $list = $this->model_masterdata_menu->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $i => $menu) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $menu->menu_id;
            $row[] = $menu->menu_nama;
            $row[] = $menu->menu_url;
            if($menu->statusmenu_nama == 'visible')
            {
              $row[] = '<form id="form_['.$i.']" method="post" action="'.site_url().'/menu/visible/'.$menu->menu_id.'">
                          <label class="switch">
                          <input type="hidden" value="0" name="cbcheck">
                          <input type="checkbox" name="visible['.$i.']" id="cb_['.$i.']" class="cb_['.$i.']" checked>
                          <span class="slider round"></span>
                          </label>
                        </form">
                        <script language=\"text/javascript\">
                        $(function(){
                         $("#cb_['.$i.']").on("change",function(){
                            $("#form_['.$i.']").submit();
                            });
                        });

                        </script>
                        ';
            }else{
              $row[] = '<form id="form2_['.$i.']" method="post" action="'.site_url().'/menu/unvisible/'.$menu->menu_id.'">
                          <label class="switch">
                          <input type="hidden" value="1" name="cbcheck">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="visible['.$i.']" id="cb2_['.$i.']" class="cb2_['.$i.']" value="1" >
                            <span class="slider round"></span>
                          </label>
                        </form>

                        <script language=\"text/javascript\">
                        $(function(){
                         $("#cb2_['.$i.']").on("change",function(){
                            $("#form2_['.$i.']").submit();
                            });
                        });
                        </script>
                        ';
            }

            $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit('."'".$menu->menu_id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hapus" onclick="hapus('."'".$menu->menu_id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->model_masterdata_menu->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->model_masterdata_menu->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
```

[image: when I switch, no request]

when I switch the button, no request.
Can anyone help me? Thank you very much

Comment: why is that block of javascript inside the controller anyway? can't you just take that out ofthere, and just include the js, and the using view files for the form html

Comment: @Ghost, I create a javascript in the controller to retrieve data and repeated arrays, Can you tell me, what's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't load JS through Ajax like that.

You should give all the elements you want to add events for the same class:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="visible['.$i.']" id="cb_['.$i.']" class="some-class" checked>
```

Then you should add the event binding on that class on the main page instead, like so:

```
$(function() {
    // Registering an event this way, the event will also be added to all elements 
    // appended to the DOM at a later point, like through ajax.
    $('body').on('change', '.some-class', function () {
        // Submit the closest form
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this way:

1. change your selector `id` to `class` and remove `javascript` code from `controller`

   ```
   $(function(){                             
     $("body").delegate(".cb2","change",function(){
         $(this).closest('form').submit
         //$("#form2_['.$i.']").submit();
     });
   });
   ```